# How to edit own k-means function so that it takes clusters as input instead of centers in R?

Tags: r, function

How could this function be edited to take 'k' (number of clusters) as an input instead of centers as is currently the case? The code is below:

```
# Calculates Eudlidean distance
euclid <- function(points1, points2) {
  distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(points1)[1], ncol=dim(points2)[1])
  for(i in 1:nrow(points2)) {
    distanceMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(points1)-points2[i,])^2))
  }
  distanceMatrix
}

# k-means algorithm
k_means = function(x, centers, distFun) {
  prevClusters = NULL
  prevCenters = NULL
  
  repeat {
    distsToCenters = distFun(x, centers)
    clusters = apply(distsToCenters, 1L, which.min)
    centers = apply(x, 2L, tapply, clusters, mean) # If I replace 'mean' here with 'centroid', error comes
    if (identical(prevClusters, clusters)) break
    
    prevClusters = clusters
    prevCenters = centers
  }
  
  list(clusters = clusters, centers = centers)
}

test=data # A data.frame
ktest=as.matrix(test) # Turn into a matrix
centers <- ktest[sample(nrow(ktest), 5),] # Sample some centers, 5 for example

res <- k_means(ktest, centers, euclid) 
print(res)
```

The result when using a matrix of data as the input is a number of clusters followed by their centers. Is it possible to edit this so that instead of the desired number of centers, you input the desired number of clusters? I.e. how can define 'clusters' so that it could be used as an input?

Comment: What is the difference between the number of centers and the number of clusters? Doesn't each cluster have a center?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest you to not reinvent the wheel, since R provides out of the box a `kmeans` implementation. However, if in your function you are just provided with the number of clusters, you can random select points inside the range of your data. Something like:

```
if (length(centers)==1) {
    k<-as.integer(centers)
    extrema<-apply(x,2,range)
    centers<-apply(extrema,2,function(.x) runif(k,.x[1],.x[2])) 
}
```

rigth at the beginning of your function.